# TYPO3 Formhandler multistep form: keep language

Tags: forms, translation, typo3

I am currently creating a multistep form with Formhandler, including a variety of translation labels. At default, German labels are shown, but there is a option to switch the website to English - when I do this, the label texts change, so this works.

**My problem:** when I submit the first step of the form in English to get to the second page, suddenly the form (and the whole website) change back to German. Of course I want it to stay in English.

Is there some kind of hidden field that has to be passed on for Formhandler to "keep" the current language? What could be the reason it loses the set language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `<input type="hidden" name="L" id="L" value="###value_L###" />` in every step of the form did the trick. It seems that the empty value automatically led to resetting the default language: in my case German.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the `linkVars` in TypoScript config?

```
config.linkVars = L
```

This means that the L parameter should stay in all URLs.

Comment: Yes, `config.linkVars = L` is set in the global TypoScript. I have also tried to include a hidden field in the form steps, but to no avail - the value is empty: `<input type="hidden" name="L" id="L" value="###value_L###" />`

Comment: Can you prove this setting in the TypoScript Object Browser on the page with the form? Is there no L-parameter in the action URL?

Comment: The action url of the Formhandler form is `action="en/base19/application/?no_cache=1"`, so there is no language parameter.

Comment: Try disabling RealURL for testing. Then you will also see your language parameter, which is translated to /en/ in the URL above. Also, you shouldn't have to use the no_cache setting - I never had to do this on my formhandler pages. Btw. I  think something in your config must be buggy, formhandler should stay in the right language. Probably you should post your Formhandler TS and most of all the part where the multistep submit button is configured.